# setInterval doesn't work without an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, screen-scraping

So i tried to watch a tutorial and make a web scraper, i combined like 5 tutorial worth code into my code so i suppose it's messy.

This is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const fs = require('fs');
const { html } = require('cheerio');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { setInterval } = require('timers/promises');
require('dotenv').config();
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid,authToken);
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
const oldData = "oldData";

async function scrape(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport:{
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080
        }
    });


    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('page');


    const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return{
            width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            html: document.documentElement.innerHTML,
        };
    })

    const $ = cheerio.load(pageData.html);
    
    const element = $(".accordion__header-inner:last");
    console.log(element.text());
};

const handle = setInterval(scrape(), 4000);
scrape();
```

I hide some parts that i didn't want to be seen.

So, when i run the code function it logged the element thing twice.
When i delete the interval thing it works only one.
That is the only difference, i want to log the element thing in every 5 seconds.

Any help is appreciated and i hope this isn't a poorly written question.

Comment: `setInterval(scrape, 4000)`, not `scrape()`

Comment: Or the usually better `setInterval(() => scrape(), 4000)`, to preserve the meaning of `this`.

Comment: sorry but it didn't work. Saying for both of the comments

Answer (score 1):

In your `setInterval` you are executing the function and passing it's return value as argument, instead of passing function itself as argument.
It should be:

```
const handle = setInterval(scrape, 4000);
```

Note, you won't be use `this` inside the function, because it will be called inside `setInterval` scope.
If you need to use `this`, then use `bind()`:

```
const handle = setInterval(scrape.bind(scrape), 4000);
```

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: "didnt' work" how?

Comment: like literally nothing changed.

Comment: It still "logged the element thing twice" ???

Comment: no it logged only once but still never logged another time, according to code it should be logged again after 4 seconds.

Comment: is this correct: const { setInterval } = require('timers/promises'); i have watched some other tutorials on youtube and never saw this.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling the "scrape()" method in two places. Once in the SetInterval() method and then immediately again on the line after. That looks like your problem.

Comment: That's not the problem - you always do this if you want to start the interval "now" as opposed to "however many milliseconds it's scheduled for, in the future". The problem is that the code for setting up the interval calls the function, instead of passing the function handle.